# Use nodejs to host multiple html websites instead of apache

Tags: node.js, apache2, hosting

I currently use Apache2 to host multiple websites for some friends, and as i've been experimenting with NodeJS I was wondering if it was possible to host these sites with NodeJs?

I wanted to have a folder structure like the following:

```
App
--> server
--> websites
   `--> site1 (example1.com)
   `--> site2 (example2.com)
```

With more people asking me to host there sites I need to be able to easily create a new site quickly with out restarting the server effecting other hosted sites.

Currently I use a bash script to create the folder structure for apache and add a new virtualhost in the apache conf file and finally reload apache.

So my main question is, should I even be looking at nodejs for this or stick with apache?

Any opinions, examples or tutorials would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off staying with apache (or possibly switching to nginx). In fact, best practice for production node.js servers is typically to run them **behind** apache/nginx through a reverse proxy. Few reasons for that:

- You have to run node.js as root to give it access to port 80/443 (generally bad idea)
- You're going to be very hard-pressed (and probably a lot of trial and error) to get the security, performance and stability of apache/nginx.